# pass parameter in this function with reference

Tags: c++

This is one function in .h file

```
LinkedListElement<char> * findLastNthElementRecursive(int n, int &current);
```

Try both

```
findLastNthElementRecursive(3,0);
```

and

```
int a = 0;
findLastNthElementRecursive(3,&a);
```

error is no matching function

I GOT IT `findLastNthElementRecursive(3,a);` SHOULE BE THIS WAY

but if I do not want to create new variable like a, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary cannot bind to a non-`const` reference. In your first case, you attempt to pass a temorary as parameter, and it fails.

The second one doesn't work because `&a` is the address of `a`, effectively an `int*`, so doesn't match the signature of the function.

The correct way would be

```
int a = 0;
findLastNthElementRecursive(3,a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int a = 0;
findLastNthElementRecursive(3, a);
```

Also note that you're ignoring the return value of `findLastNthElementRecursive()`.